# Adding page specific js using timber twig

Tags: wordpress, timber

I have a twig file that extends base

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}
  {% block content %}
    <div> all articles </div>   
    {% for blog in blog_articles %}
        <div><i> {{blog.post_title }}</i></div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

base.twig has an include for my global js and in my article.twig above i want to be able to add template specific JS that will appear below the global js that is in an include in base.twig

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question i did this

in the base.twig

```
 {% include 'globaljs.twig' %}
 {% block javascript %}{% endblock %}
```

Then in the article.twig where i call the javascript block i just add my page scripts. simple